# ISC-KEA - kea-legal hook - database backend mysql unsupported?

Tags: mysql, networking, dhcp, centos8

Im attempting to set up the kea-legal hook to log to a mysql database. The database exists and the "logs" schema also exists.

This is what Ive got for my kea-dhcp4.conf hooks configuration:

```
"hooks-libraries": [{
"library": "/usr/local/lib/kea/hooks/libdhcp_legal_log.so",
"parameters": {
"name": "DHCP",
"password": "password",
"type": "mysql",
"user": "root"
}
}],
```

I receive this error in the logs:

> An error occurred loading the library: Database access parameter
> 'type' does not specify a supported database backend: mysql

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like when I did the ./configure to build kea, I didnt run the --with-mysql tag.. 

So Im rebuilding.. Ill come back with results.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Kea with MySQL, you have to run ./configure --with-mysql when installing.

Works fine now..